# Fragments memory leaks

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, memory-leaks

I have only one activity and all navigation is solved through fragments. If I open the fragment and come back, the fragment will be still in memory and memory will be growing.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to manually remove listeners? In the `onDestroy` method, `getView` is already null.

How I add fragments:

```
    fun replaceFragment(
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager?,
        fragment: Fragment?,
        frameId: Int,
        tag: String?
    ) {
        if (fragmentManager != null && fragment != null) {
            val previousFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(frameId)
            if (fragment != previousFragment) {
                val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(frameId, fragment, tag)
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag)
                transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
            }
        }
    }
```

Fragment close by the back button:

EDIT:
How I create Fragment

```
    companion object {
        fun create(number: Long): ManageUnitFragment {
            val fragment = ManageUnitFragment()

            val params = Bundle()
            params.putLong(Keys.Number, number)
            fragment.arguments = params

            return fragment
        }
    }
```

How I set Listeners (on buttons)

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.myFragment.*

        vMyButton.setOnClickListener {
            myAction()
        }
```

EDIT
If I remove this line `vButtonClose.setOnClickListener...` , the ManageUnitFragments will no longer be in the heap dump.

ManageUnitFragment:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_manage_unit.*

class ManageUnitFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_unit, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        vButtonClose.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(unitNumber: Long, wagonWagonUnit: WagonUnit): ManageUnitFragment {
            val fragment = ManageUnitFragment()
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Heap dump]

Comment: Please add more code so we can help. How are you switching between different fragments?

Comment: Could you please add more code? What listeners are they? If the object you are adding the fragment as listeners outlives the fragments then yes, you should remove them. If you don't then your fragment will not be Garbage collected

Comment: Check the updated code.

Comment: `onDestroyView` maybe?

Comment: Add Heap Dump file if you can and i don't see any file/class leaked in image you attached. How are you assuming fragment is leaked.

Comment: I suspect your `if (fragment != previousFragment) {` fails, therefore adding the fragment multiple times. Replace the check with `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null)` If it works I will add it as answer

Comment: I'd use `if (!fragment.isAdded()) {` instead of `if (fragment != previousFragment) {`.

Comment: Better to post full `ManageUnitFragment` code. There are could be different leak causes.

Comment: @Praveen Because I see 6x ManageUnitFragment (in image screen)

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous @Ircover - Not work, It`s always new instance of fragment.

Comment: @Ircover - check updated code

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add 'many' fragments? Do you actually get `OutOfMemoryException`?

Maybe they just remain in memory until more of it is needed. Then they will be garbage collected.

Comment: But if I click the back button I won't get to the previous fragmnet

Comment: I think you should just replace the fragment in onBackPressed the same way you did it above.

Comment: No I call replaceFragment to open next fragment and backPress to close fragment.